# Inherit from a Class Which Name Is Composed Using the `&` character in Less

Tags: less

How can I inherit from a class which name is composed using the `&` character (e.g. `&-rule`), please?

#### Desired Output

```
.prefix-rule-extended,
.prefix-rule {
    color: white;
}
.prefix-rule-extended {
    background-color: black;
}
```

or

```
.prefix-rule {
    color: white;
}
.prefix-rule-extended {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

#### Non-working Approaches

```
.prefix {
    &-rule {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

plus

```
.prefix-rule-extended:extend(.prefix-rule) {
    background-color: black;
}
```

or

```
.prefix-rule-extended {
    .prefix-rule();
    background-color: black;
}
```

#### Ideal Approach

```
.prefix {
    &-rule {
        color: white;
    }
    &-rule-extended:extend(&-rule) {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

Note 1: I know `:extend(&-rule)` is currently not supported.

Note 2: `.prefix-rule` is not so simple, i.a. there are nested rules inside so the following will not work:

```
.prefix {
    &-rule {
        color: white;

        &-extended {
            background-color: black;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Currently there's no way. So just do not try to nest so deadly and use either [(semi-)complete class names](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/d9e79b290e9c7e0926e3#file-25791230-1-less) and/or [dummy base style(s)](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/f963a9ac999bf5a9f18c#file-25791230-2-less).

Comment: In addition to seven-phases-max's above comment, nested rules can also be inherited using the `all` keyword within the `extend` function call.

Comment: Indeed, the [third option](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/0508fd4829c35376535e#file-25791230-3-less) inspired by @Harry's comment. Note however this one will work only for complete `.prefix-rule` name and not for the concatenated one (i.e. `.prefix {&-rule { ...`).

Comment: Thank you both. The options are very inspiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Ok, so as always to not leave this one w/o an answer - a summary of comments above):

Currently it's impossible to `extend` that kind of things. For the moment `extend` can't match selector identifiers generated via "concatenation" so `.prefix {&.rule { ...` would be a valid `extend` target (as it's "two elements" -> "two identifiers") but `.prefix {&-rule { ...` won't (since it's "two elements" -> "one identifier").

So if you plan to use `extend` don't be keen on such kind of nesting, keep it more simple.
Here are three valid Less snippets (each having its pros and cons) to get the desired CSS output.

**1**:

```
.prefix-rule {
    color: white;
    &-extended:extend(.prefix-rule) {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

**2**:

```
.prefix-rule {
    &, &-extended {
        color: white;
    }
    &-extended {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

**3**:

```
.rule-base {
    color: white;
}

.prefix-rule {
    &:extend(.rule-base);
    &-extended:extend(.rule-base) {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think none of these options solve my problem the most imaginable elegant way (no repetitions), but they are the best available. Cheers.

Comment: @Jan, If you are adored about total no-repetitions than it's better to solve this at the HTML level (as it will also remove any repetitions in the generated CSS by removing ~20 extra characters of the redundant selector): **[codepen](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/AdeGo)**.